# Python dict value query without iterating

Tags: python

I have a dict like below:

```
 s = {1: True, 2: False, 3: False}
```

I want to find out if there exists any key in the dict with a value of False.
Is there any way to find out without iterating all the keys of the dict?
Basically, I can do something like if 2 in s to find out if a given key exists in the dict.
Is there anything like it for the value of the keys in the dict?

Comment: No. That is using the dictionary backwards.

Comment: backwards as in ? Could you kindly clarify ?

Comment: Backwards as in you're supposed to look up a key to retrieve its associated value, not the other way around.

Comment: The linked question is rather old and the answers are for Python 2. The best way in Python 3 is `if False in s.values():`. It has to do a linear scan of the values, so it's not as efficient as testing for a dict key, or an element in a set, but it's faster than manually looping over the dict's values.